# list menu underline for each page

Tags: css, paging, underline

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/product/list.html?cate_no=1">menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/product/list.html?cate_no=2">menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/product/list.html?cate_no=3">menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

using jquery,
if I click menu 1, I want to make underline on list "menu 1".
and if click menu 2, show underline on only "menu 2".

Please Help!

Comment: you need javascript to do this. You cant do it just with css

Comment: Each page recognize list menu and show underline.

Comment: How could I make these with css?

Comment: what do u mean by list menu 1 ?

Comment: I want to show underline on each menu in each page.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("a").on( "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("a").css( "text-decoration", "none" );
    $(this).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
});
```